# Safari blank page SharePoint portal

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, sharepoint

We are working on a SharePoint Portal and facing some weird issue with iOS devices (safari browser). At times, as we navigate from page to page, sometimes a next page will not load. browser stays white (blank page). No errors. F5(browser refresh) takes care of it and the page loads fine.

We researched this issue over google and found that people are discussing about this & there is no concrete fix for it except clearing browser cache (in code or manually).

Has anyone had experienced similar issues with iOS devices before & found any working solution for this issue? Any insight would be really appreciated!!

Thanks.

Vishal

Comment: Is it only the white page or do you get any errors. Are there any errors when you open the console on a pc

Comment: Thanks..Its only white page, no erros, looks like the page itself hasnt been processed.

Comment: Can't help you since we don't know anything of why it is happening